# Oracle: Get Results for everything before 12 am today

Tags: sql, oracle

```
      WHERE (internalagentname is not null or internalagentcode is not null)
      and (source LIKE '%GETAWAY%' or source like '%VACATION%')  
      and initialbookingdate <= to_Date(to_char(sysdate-1,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 
      'MM/DD/YYYY')
      and  (ABS(total_revenue) + ABS(total_cost) + ABS(booking_adjustment))<>0
```

so, this is my final step query were I am pulling data from yesterdays date. unfortunately its reading this as sysdate - 1 (from current time) so that's why it has data from today current date as well, how can i change this so it only takes out data from 12 am and before? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should simply be using the logic:

```
initialbookingdate < trunc(sysdate - 1)
```

The problem is the `<=`.  The current time has nothing to do with the issue, because there is no time component in the conversion back to a date.  Nevertheless, your expression is way more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: how would this look with the to_Date and to_char functions. i need those to change the format of the date

Comment: @Kamran . . . No, you do not need to change the format of the date.  Date comparisons should be handled using date/time functions.

Comment: why is showing data from todays date then...can you please explain sorry still in college and learning

Comment: @Kamran: please edit the question (there's an `edit` button below the tags, which are below the question text) and include some test data, the results you're getting, and the results you expected. Even with the `WHERE` clause as shown in your query I wouldn't expect you'd be getting data where `INITIALBOOKINGDATE` is the current date. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that you need data that belongs to "yesterday", have a look at this:

```
SQL> select
  2    sysdate right_now,
  3    trunc(sysdate) todays_midnight,
  4    trunc(sysdate - 1) yesterdays_midnight
  5  from dual;

RIGHT_NOW           TODAYS_MIDNIGHT     YESTERDAYS_MIDNIGHT
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
21.03.2018 21:31:46 21.03.2018 00:00:00 20.03.2018 00:00:00

SQL>
```

It means that one option is to select values whose `initialbookingdate` is between "yesterdays_midnignt" and "todays_midnight", i.e.

```
where initialbookingdate between trunc(sysdate - 1) and trunc(sysdate)
```

(note that BETWEEN is *inclusive*).

A simpler option, which would ruin index you might have on `initialbookingdate` (so - although simpler, use it with caution. On small data amount you wouldn't see problems, but when handling many rows - yes, you would) is

```
where trunc(initialbookingdate) = trunc(sysdate - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code in your query condition,

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM';

SELECT TRUNC(sysdate)-(.00019/24) date_ 
  FROM dual;

DATE_                
----------------------
03/21/2018 11:59:59 PM
```